# Database logic for user achievments

Tags: database, google-app-engine, mobile, logic

I have a table in my database that stores users, for example:

```
userID | userName | email | password | wins | losses | exp
```

Now I want the user to be able to get achievments in my game, like "win 5 games in a row", and I obviously want that progress in the database (Google app-engine) so progress is not lost when user exits client. Example of achievment table:

```
achievmentID | achievmentTitle | description | reward
```

Now how would I go about saving achievment progress for each user in the best manner? I need to save both progress (like 3/5 games in a row won) and if achievment is completed or not.

The product is for Android/iOS and uses google app engine (datastore) as database.

Answer (score 0):

The way you set up your table would not be very efficient. In my mind to be the most efficient, you would have to make a new column on your users table (not new table, but after the 'exp') and create a sort of key for achievements. For example, you could give each achievement an ID (which you would keep track of like in a notes on notepad or something).

Then, when they get that achievement, you would put "123/" and if you did another achievement, it would say something like "123/461/".

Then you could make a script that breaks apart these IDs to see what achievements have been completed.

Comment: Lemme know what you think

Comment: If you have a suggestion for a better way to set it up please let me know, I can change that

Comment: I made a suggestion. It's my answer above

Comment: I see, well this game is for android/ios so there is no notepad. And I would not even know where to start with building a script. This solution is the one I had in mind too btw, so nice to know Im not way off